# Excel VBA macro for enumerating the combinations of r elements out of N elements

Tags: excel, vba, combinations

The original code in Box 1 and the code in Box 2 are published on [this](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14208784379) Q＆A site . But, originally written in Japanese, so I translated to English with minor modifications. Both of them seems to be **intended to enumerating the combinations of r elements out of N elements**. However, I don't understand the principle behind the Box1's code.

**My question**

> - How can the Box1's macro list all the combinations that choose r elements from among N elements?　I want to know mathematical principles of Box1's code.

I understand the principle of Box2's code.

**Note 1:**　The logic of the Box2 code is as follows;

> - Each number below 2^N-1 is written in binary notation.
> - Consider the bits corresponding to 2^i to be the  `i-th`  element.
> - Consider the  `i-th`  element as chosen if it is 1 and not chosen if it is 0.
> - Thus, any combination of that "selects n "or less" elements" are listed.
> - Only those with exactly k number of 1's are left.

Simply, Box2's logic is a logic such that only the sets which satisfies the following condition survive;
**Condition: "Number of elements whose bit=1" is r.**

The code in Box 1 seems to export essentially the same results, but with fewer calculations.
Actually, after much experimentation, export of the Box1's code and Box2's code are essentially same. For example, Table 1 below shows the output for  `N = 5 and r = 3` . It displays 0 for the elements we don't choose and 1 for the elements we do choose.

> But why can the code in Box 1 output the Essentially equivalent results to Box2's code?

Table1.A list of combinations, such that choosing 3 elements out of 5 elements
[image]

You can download XLSM file having both Box1's and Box2's macro from [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13ta30ywd8QyIKueyrkvbF7WojviupVld?usp=sharing).

Box1.

```
    Sub Cmb()
    Dim n, r, m, i, j, c(), o()
      n = 5 'Please specify the N
      r = 3 'Please specify the r
      m = WorksheetFunction.Combin(n, r)
      ReDim c(r), o(m, n)
      For j = 0 To r: c(j) = j: Next
      o(0, 0) = "Decimal"
      For j = 1 To n: o(0, j) = "Elements" & j: Next
      i = 1
      Do While c(0) <= 0
        For j = 0 To n: o(i, j) = 0: Next
        For j = 1 To r
          o(i, 0) = o(i, 0) + 2 ^ (c(j) - 1)
          o(i, n + 1 - c(j)) = 1
        Next
        i = i + 1
        nc n, r, c
      Loop
      Cells(1, 1).Resize(m + 1, n + 1).Value = o
    End Sub
    
    
    Sub nc(n, r, ByRef c())
      Dim j, k
      For j = r To 0 Step -1
        c(j) = c(j) + 1
        For k = j + 1 To r: c(k) = c(k - 1) + 1: Next
        If c(j) <= n - r + j Then Exit For
      Next
    End Sub
```

Box2.

```
    Sub enumeration_of_combinations()
    Dim table_()
    n = 5
    r = 3
    
    Number_of_elements = WorksheetFunction.Combin(n, r)
    ReDim table_(1 To Number_of_elements)
    
    cnt = 1
    Nmax = (2 ^ n) - 1
    For i = 1 To Nmax
    Number_of_bits = 0: modulo_ = i
    For j = 0 To n
    Quotient_ = modulo_ \ 2 ^ (n - j)
    modulo_ = modulo_ Mod 2 ^ (n - j)
    Number_of_bits = Number_of_bits + Quotient_
    Next j
    If Number_of_bits = r Then
    table_(cnt) = i: cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To Number_of_elements
    modulo_ = table_(i)
    For j = 0 To n
    Quotient_ = modulo_ \ 2 ^ (n - j)
    modulo_ = modulo_ Mod 2 ^ (n - j)
    Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = Quotient_
    Next j
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = table_(i)
    Next i
    Cells(1, 1) = "Decimal": For j = 1 To n: Cells(1, j + 1) = "element" & j: Next j
    
    End Sub
```

**Reference.** 
https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14208784379  (Written in Japanese)

Comment: So you don't understand the code and wants the community to explain it to you? That's not exactly how SO works.

Comment: @FunThomas Thank you for your comment. I'm looking for a mathematical explanation. I want the Box1 version of  the "The logic of the Box2 code is as follows."

Comment: I Clarified the question. The questions I want to ask is very clear. That's simply why the purpose can be achieved by the Box 1's code. If there is a Box 1 version of the "Note1 " that will be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you should do:

1. break all those single-line For-Next cycle to make them easily readable by you;
2. rename all the variables with name made of multiple letters (at least 3 each) that has some sense according to the use the code make of them. To determine it, search for them in the code and interpret it;
3. if the purpose of one variable is not clear, try with another one;
4. if you still can't figure the purpose of some of the variables, use the immediate and local window while stopping the code during its execution. With this code you can also run the code once to have the result on sheet and re-run and stop it.
5. write the appropriate notes.

You should end with something like this:

```
Sub SubCombinations()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim TotalBits, PositiveBits, CombinationsCount, Counter01, Counter02, ExponentsArray(), ResultArray()
    
    'Setting variables.
    TotalBits = 5 'Please specify the N
    PositiveBits = 3 'Please specify the r
    CombinationsCount = WorksheetFunction.Combin(TotalBits, PositiveBits)
    
    'Reallocating variables.
    ReDim ExponentsArray(PositiveBits), ResultArray(CombinationsCount, TotalBits)
    
    'Setting the starting position of the ExponentsArray. This will result in the first line having all the 1 on the right.
    For Counter02 = 0 To PositiveBits
        ExponentsArray(Counter02) = Counter02
    Next
    
    'Setting the headers.
    ResultArray(0, 0) = "Decimal"
    For Counter02 = 1 To TotalBits
        ResultArray(0, Counter02) = "Elements" & Counter02
    Next
    
    'Setting variable.
    Counter01 = 1
    
    'When ExponentsArray(0) will be greater than 0, we will have covered all possible combinations.
    Do While ExponentsArray(0) <= 0
        
        'Set all the bits in the given result row as 0.
        For Counter02 = 0 To TotalBits
            ResultArray(Counter01, Counter02) = 0
        Next
        
        'Covering all the positive bits requested for the row.
        For Counter02 = 1 To PositiveBits
          
          'Increasing the decimal result by 2 elevated by the power of the value of attributed to the given bit.
          ResultArray(Counter01, 0) = ResultArray(Counter01, 0) + 2 ^ (ExponentsArray(Counter02) - 1)
          
          'Reporting the positive bit in its proper location on the row.
          ResultArray(Counter01, TotalBits + 1 - ExponentsArray(Counter02)) = 1
          
        Next
        
        'Setting Counter01 to cover the next row.
        Counter01 = Counter01 + 1
        
        'Calling SubExponentsShift
        SubExponentsShift TotalBits, PositiveBits, ExponentsArray
    Loop
    
    'Reporting the results.
    Cells(1, 1).Resize(CombinationsCount + 1, TotalBits + 1).Value = ResultArray
    
End Sub

Sub SubExponentsShift(TotalBits, PositiveBits, ByRef ExponentsArray())
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim Counter01, Counter02
    
    'Covering all the values in the ExponentsArray.
    For Counter01 = PositiveBits To 0 Step -1
        
        'Increasing the exponent value. This will make "the given bit shift to the left".
        ExponentsArray(Counter01) = ExponentsArray(Counter01) + 1
        
        'If we have "shifted" a bit that was not the first on the right, we have to correct the overshoot of the other bit "shifted" previously.
        For Counter02 = Counter01 + 1 To PositiveBits
            ExponentsArray(Counter02) = ExponentsArray(Counter02 - 1) + 1
        Next
        
        'If we have overshoot while "shifting the position" of the given bit, the For-Next cycle continues.
        If ExponentsArray(Counter01) <= TotalBits - PositiveBits + Counter01 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

It will then be easier to realize how the code works. The subroutine actually sets the starting conditions and produce each row of the result while the function focuses on "shifting the position" of the bits for each row of the result. Matematically speaking, the code just increase metodically the exponents of given set of powers of 2 whose result are then sum; this goes on until all the unique combinations are covered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, thanks for making the names of the variables make sense and adding your comments.
I still don't understand the principle  of "shifting the position"  such that  keeping the "number of elements with bit=1" to r, but I'll take a closer look at the code you've modified.

Comment: The hardest part to understand (at least for me) is the function. It's easier to visualize when looking at the final result. The first row is set as 00111. The ExponentsArray keeps track of where the ones has to be placed starting from the right (5th-4th-3rd-2nd-1st position). At the first round the ExponentsArray has 0-1-2-3 as 0=control, 1=1st position, 2=2nd position, 3=3rd position. The function do its thing and at the second round ExponentArray has changed to 0-1-2-4 as [same as previous but] 4=4th position. Changing the 3 in 0123 to 4 makes a 1 "shift" from the 3rd position to the 4th.

Comment: Thank you for your additional comment.　The first decimal number $= \sum_{i=0}^{r}{2^i}$. 
Looking at Decimal's gradations from top to bottom, the movement seems to be as follows;
4,8,16... ,reached upper limit and back, 
8,16,... ,reached upper limit and back,.... 

Let's write "a function that counts the number of elements whose bits are 1" as "count_bit". I think the first gradations implies that "if count_bit(decimal) = r, then count_bit(decimal+4)=r."
I have not yet read the logic to back.